# Why Ripple is not able to sign my app?

Tags: cordova, blackberry-webworks, ripple

I'm using **Ripple** to package and sign my **phonegap** app for Blackberry 7.0 and earlier devices using **Blackberry web works sdk**.

What has successfully been done:

1. Installed all the 3 .csi files. ([Link used](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Manually-register-CSI-files/ta-p/445787))
2. Changed the bbwp.properties files in the bin folder. ([Link used](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/SignatureTool-Stops-Responding-While-Signing/ta-p/1286833))

But when i try to Package & Build it just gives me "Build succeeded" alert.
But when i check the output folder only project.zip file present there.Instead it should give me the OTA install and Standard install.

This is my second attempt where i configured the whole environment from scratch.

**History:**
In my very first attempt, where everything was fresh installed.
It successfully gave me the output files named *OTA install* and *STANDARD install* and signature tool opened up where it started connecting to their server for signing but that process never ended and have to close that forcefully.

Then after googling, i found that mistakenly i'm using java SE 7 which is not the required if you are targeting BB o.s 7 and earlier so i edited the bbwp.properties file and after that it started behaving like what i just explained above(only producing project.zip file)

Can anyone explain me if i'm getting the correct output from Ripple (only zip file) after using Package and sign option?

If yes, then how to proceed further?

If no, then how to fix this?

Any kinda help will highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone explain me if i'm getting the correct output from Ripple
>   (only zip file) after using Package and sign option?

Answer is, No i wasn't getting the correct output.

> If yes, then how to proceed further?

N.A

> If no, then how to fix this?

I redid all the installation process for java jdk , blackberry web works.
Before doing uninstall of blackberry web works make sure ypu back up the two files named:
**signtool.csk** and **signtool.db** these files get created after you successfully install the singning keys sent by Blackberry( earlier RIM).

As you/i are/am developing for blackberry 7.0 and earlier so we need to install the older java jdk. 
**But here comes the catch** -- Make sure you do not download this version **Java SE Development Kit 6u45** instead you should download **Java SE Development Kit 6u43**.

The later version has some compatibility issues with what setup of blackbery web works i'm using which is: 2.3.1.5 and make sure that path where you install the web works should not have any spaces within the path.

And yes while you do fresh install don't forget to put those .csk and .db files back to the bin folder of your installed backberry webwork sdk.

This solved my problem :)